# Why Fiddler can not inject javascript on certain domains?

Tags: http, fiddler

I am using Fiddler to inject a javascript library onto the page using:

```
oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('</head>','<script src="//third_party_domain.com/js_file.js"></script></head>');
```

What would be the reason why this would not work on a certain secure (HTTPS) domain? It seems to work on every other domain I try this on (http <strike>and https</strike>).

I think it is related to Fiddler, as I know this has worked in the past - so perhaps it's a configuration setting I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe `</head>` just doesn't exist in the response...

Comment: It does.. I'm noticing now that it just doesn't work on secure sites, but it has in the past :/

Comment: Are you still decrypting the https? http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Comment: No, Decrypt HTTPS is unchecked altogether... should it be enabled?

Comment: Yes, That is why I asked...

Comment: THANK YOU!! I had tried that setting before but forgot to restart fiddler for it to take effect. This time it worked. Thanks so much! please copy your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddler can not read HTTPS pages unless it is configured to decrypt them. Check the checkboxes below on the HTTPS tab in Fiddler's options.

[image: Fiddler's HTTPS tab]

[Details](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS)